# Express.js: How to get actual image file to check magic bytes in Multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm using `fileFilter` option of `multer` plugin to decide whether the image should be saved onto the server or not.

In that `fileFilter` function, I want to check `magic bytes` of these images to ensure they are real images and in right format. `Multer` only expose **file** which is `json array` of uploaded image file as follow. But I need **actual image file** to check `magic bytes`.

```
{ fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'arsenal-home-kit.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg' }
```

I comment my detail problem in the following code. My attempt so far as below;

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: __dirname + '/../public/images/',
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        console.log(file.originalname);
        crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function (err, raw) {
            if (err) return cb(err);

            cb(null, raw.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname))
        })
    }
});
var upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: function (req, theFile, cb) {
            // using image-type plugin to check magic bytes
            // I need actual image file right at here.
            // theFile is json array, not the image file.
            // How to I get the actual image file to check magic bytes.
            if (imageType(theFile).ext === "jpg") {
                // To accept the file pass `true`, like so:
                cb(null, true);
            } else {
                // To reject this file pass `false`, like so:
                cb(null, false);
            }
        }
    });
```

P.S. I decided to use [image-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-type) plugin to check these magic bytes.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If yes I have question: how do you use image-type with multer?

Answer (score 2):

fileFilter is called before start file upload, therefore it has no access to file data.
this is similar request https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/155
as you see it is in roadmap.

Currently you can download file to temporary directory, then validate it and move to destination directory or delete.

In my applications i use two types of validators: first before upload (very limited) and second type after upload (mime check can be after ).

Comment: This is a bit late, but can you share your validators please?

Comment: @Neta Im sorry, but I didn't find any proper code fragment (everything with to much additional logic or in to high abstract level). Maybe write what validator you need or what you wish to accomplish? -as new question